# Android - SharedPreferences and NullPointException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

**EDIT**: The problem was not the SharedPreference! It was my wav-data. Android supports only 8- and 16-bit linear PCM wave formats. I used a 32-bit float.

today I recieved a error report via BugSense. A User had a NullPointException because of the sharedPreferences. I recieved this error for the first time.

Here is my relevant code:

The Settings where I set the sharedPreference:

```
private void dialogSettings() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.dialog_style);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_settings);
    final CheckBox sound = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSound);
    final CheckBox vibration = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxVibration);
    final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 0);
    sound.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("SOUND", true));
    vibration.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("VIBRATION", true));
    Button buttonSave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {       
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("SOUND", sound.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean("VIBRATION", vibration.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

The use of "SOUND" (other Activity):

```
private boolean SOUND;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_normal_layout);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 0);
    SOUND = pref.getBoolean("SOUND", true); 
    ....
}

private void evaluateAnswer() {
    if(correct) {
        if(SOUND) {  // LINE 259
            ding.seekTo(0);
            ding.start();
        }
    ...
}
```

And here is the Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at mindmApp.quiz.GameNormalActivity.evaluateAnswer(GameNormalActivity.java:259)
```

So, the variable SOUND is null. But why? Because of SOUND = pref.getBoolean("SOUND", true) it **must** be initialised, or not?

Thanks for all help,

best regards!

Comment: SOUND is a primitive boolean, so it can not be null. Maybe the line count is wrong and the real cause is that *ding* is null.

Comment: I think I have found the answer. Android supports only 8- and 16-bit linear PCM wave formats. I used a 32-bit float. 

So sorry for the trouble and still thanks!

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOUND can't be null (booleans are a primitive type, which can be uninitialized, but not null).  The more likely answer is that "ding" is null.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake! Here are the lines for *ding*:

    private MediaPlayer ding;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_normal_layout); 
        ding = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ding);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        ...
    }

Comment: The comment butchers the formatting :P  Can you add to the original post?

Comment: I think I have found the answer. Android supports only 8- and 16-bit linear PCM wave formats. I used a 32-bit float. 

So sorry for the trouble and still thanks!

Best regards!